# How to trigger Ansible Play for every iteration of a loop

Tags: loops, ansible

Below registered variable `command_result` gets records from the database which could be multi-line.

The below helps me loop over each record of the database in the `command_result` variable.

```
   - debug:
       msg: "This is a database line: {{ item }}"
     with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"
```

What I, now, need is to trigger a fresh play like below for every loop iteration along with the respective `{{ item }}`.

```
- hosts: "{{ item.stdout.split('\t')[0] }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Check if reboot is required
      shell: /home/ansible/scripts/check.sh "{{ item.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}"
      register: output

    - debug: var=output.stdout_lines

    - add_host: name={{ item }}
               groups=dest_nodes
               ansible_user={{ USER }}
     with_items: "{{ dest_ip.split(',') }}"
```

The item value will change on each loop and that will be fed to the play above.

Thus in summary: if the database returns three records in `{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}` the shell module play should be invoked thrice with the details of each record in `{{ item }}` respectively.

For example: 
The database can return any number of rows and lets consider it returns three rows of type: `<listofhosts>\t<somearguments>`:

```
host5,host8\targ1
host6,host2\targ3
host9,host3,host4\targ4
```

What I need is that the loop `with_items: {{ command_result.stdout_lines }}` would run three plays and each play to build dynamic host group of the host list for that run and its respective argument.

So:

- for the first run dynamic hosts group will be `host5,host8` and the shell should get `arg1`
- for second loop iteration dynamic hosts group will be `host6,host2` and shell would get `arg3`
- and so forth.

Hope this makes my requirement understood.

I'm on the latest version of Ansible.

Comment: What I don't really get is the fact that the add_host of the "play you want to invoke on every iteration" is not linked to your database data. So it will just try to add the same hosts multiple times to the group `dest_nodes`, wouldn't it? Maybe I am missing something here

Comment: I have updated the original post with a better explanation of the requirement.

Comment: Clearer requirement indeed :) I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run this kind of task with the creation of a dynamic host group, via the module [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html).

Also, to fulfil the requirement that there will be multiple hosts per line, we are first recreating a clean list, with the help of the module [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html).
Then, with the newly created list, we can use the loop [`with_subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements), in order to create the right tuples `(check_arg, host)`.

Here is an example, where I faked you database output in the `dynamic_hosts` variable of the play:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    dynamic_hosts:
      - "host5,host8\targ1"
      - "host6,host2\targ3"
      - "host9,host3,host4\targ4"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dynamic_hosts }}"

    - name: Make a clean list out of the hosts and arguments
      set_fact:
         hosts: "{{ hosts | default([]) + [ {'hosts': item.split('\t')[0].split(','), 'check_arg': item.split('\t')[1]} ] }}"
      with_items: "{{ dynamic_hosts }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hosts }}"

    - name: Adding hosts to a dynamic group based on the faked database output stored in hosts
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item.1 }}"
        check_arg: "{{ item.0.check_arg }}"
        ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
        ansible_connection: local
        groups: nodes_to_run_on
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ hosts }}"
        - hosts

- hosts: nodes_to_run_on
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Run the shell with the argument `{{ check_arg }}` here"
```

As you can see, I am creating a host group named `nodes_to_run_on` on the first part of the play, with the help of `add_host`. Later on, I am using this host group to run a new set of tasks on all the hosts in that group.
This would be the output of this playbook:

```
PLAY [127.0.0.1] **********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": [
        "host5,host8\targ1",
        "host6,host2\targ3",
        "host9,host3,host4\targ4"
    ]
}

TASK [Make a clean list out of the hosts and arguments] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=host5,host8    arg1)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=host6,host2    arg3)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=host9,host3,host4  arg4)

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "check_arg": "arg1",
            "hosts": [
                "host5",
                "host8"
            ]
        },
        {
            "check_arg": "arg3",
            "hosts": [
                "host6",
                "host2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "check_arg": "arg4",
            "hosts": [
                "host9",
                "host3",
                "host4"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Adding hosts to a dynamic group based on the faked database output stored in hosts] *********************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{'check_arg': 'arg1'}, 'host5'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{'check_arg': 'arg1'}, 'host8'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{'check_arg': 'arg3'}, 'host6'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{'check_arg': 'arg3'}, 'host2'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{'check_arg': 'arg4'}, 'host9'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{'check_arg': 'arg4'}, 'host3'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[{'check_arg': 'arg4'}, 'host4'])

PLAY [nodes_to_run_on] ****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host5] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg1` here"
}
ok: [host8] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg1` here"
}
ok: [host6] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg3` here"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg3` here"
}
ok: [host9] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}
ok: [host4] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host4                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host5                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host6                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host8                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host9                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Please note:** this is not a really [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) list of host we are creating here, but it keeps the solution naive and is more achieving a [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.

The inventory we end up generating here would look like this:

```
## kiss.yml ## lots of repetition
nodes_to_run_on:
  hosts:
    host5:
      check_arg: arg1
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_connection: local
    host8:
      check_arg: arg1
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_connection: local
    host6:
      check_arg: arg3
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_connection: local
    host2:
      check_arg: arg3
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_connection: local
    host9:
      check_arg: arg4
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_connection: local
    host3:
      check_arg: arg4
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_connection: local
    host4:
      check_arg: arg4
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_connection: local
```

When it could definitely be dried out to

```
## dry.yaml ## no repetition with the help of group variables
nodes_to_run_on:
  vars:
    ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
    ansible_connection: local
  children:
    with_arg1:
      hosts:
        host5:
        host8:
      vars:
        check_arg: arg1
    with_arg3:
      hosts:
        host6:
        host2:
      vars:
        check_arg: arg3
    with_arg4:
      hosts:
        host9:
        host3:
        host4:
      vars:
        check_arg: arg4
```

Consider those two run in this play:

```
---
- hosts: nodes_to_run_on
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Run the shell with the argument `{{ check_arg }}` here"
```

With `kiss.yml`

```
$ ansible-playbook example.yml --inventory=kiss.yml

PLAY [nodes_to_run_on] ****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host5] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg1` here"
}
ok: [host8] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg1` here"
}
ok: [host6] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg3` here"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg3` here"
}
ok: [host9] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}
ok: [host4] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************
host2                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host4                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host5                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host6                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host8                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host9                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

With `dry.yml`

```
$ ansible-playbook example.yml --inventory=dry.yml

PLAY [nodes_to_run_on] ****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host5] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg1` here"
}
ok: [host8] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg1` here"
}
ok: [host6] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg3` here"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg3` here"
}
ok: [host9] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}
ok: [host4] => {
    "msg": "Run the shell with the argument `arg4` here"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************
host2                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host4                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host5                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host6                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host8                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host9                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

So, you can see that we achieve the same with an inventory, `dry.yml`, of 24 lines, when the `kiss.yml` inventory was 30 lines long.

But ultimately the effort to create an inventor that would be DRY would not really pay, if the source is, either way, coming from a database that would generate a host list.

Comment: my requirement is slightly different. I have updated my original post with an example to better explain my requirement.

Comment: Works perfect except when name: "{{ item.split('\t')[0] }}" returns multiple hostnames separated by commas (,)